# How do I get a pseudoelement behind its parent but in front of its grandparent with absolute positioning?

Tags: html, css, z-index, pseudo-element

Consider a situation like:

```
<div id="one"/>
<div id="two">
   <div id="three"/>
</div>
<div id="four"/>
```

I'd like to give three a pseudoelement that appears behind it but in front of two (and any other ancestors if there were more). What's complicating this for me is that I'm using a UI framework that generates HTML and CSS so I can't do something specific for this one case -- it must work in general. The framework generates divs that use absolute positioning so assume one, two, and four are absolutely positioned. Three and its pseudoelement could have different position values as long as they behave right.

z-index -1 on the pseudo works great locally, but makes it appear behind two. Okay, create a new stacking context on three by setting its z-index to 0 but that doesn't work right. I think I'm misunderstanding the whole stacking context thing.

If you wonder what I'm really doing, I'm trying to add rounded gradient border support to the framework.

Comment: Could you create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), this is hard to follow. Can't you give `.two` a z-index of 1, `.three::before` a z-index of 2 and `.three` a z-index of 3?

Comment: Here's a fiddle to play around with: https://jsfiddle.net/36p4d21h/

That doesn't appear to work. Also, ideally, I wouldn't have to go up and down the tree modifying multiple z-indices. 

I just may have to suck it up and use a extra real div.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, your jsfiddle is much clearer. You can achieve this by giving your pseudo element a negative `z-index`.

Note that your `div#three` needs to keep the default z-index `auto`. If you apply an integer to it, it will create a new [stacking context](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-position-3/#det-stacking-context), and since it would be the base of that stacking context, no child element would be able to fall behind.

`z-index` is actually a little less straightforward than most people think. [Here's a great article if you're interested](https://philipwalton.com/articles/what-no-one-told-you-about-z-index/).

PS `div`s are not self closing, so be sure to write a proper closing tag.

```css
div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  position: absolute;
}

#one {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  background: red;
}

#two {
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
  background: green;
  z-index: 1;
}

#three {
  top: 40px;
  left: 40px;
  background: lightblue;
}

#three::before {
  position: absolute;
  width: 200px;
  height: inherit;
  background: orange;
  content: '3 before';
  top: -20px;
  left: -20px;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div id="one">1</div> 
<div id="two">
  2
  <div id="three">3</div>
</div>
```